# What is the use of a predicate that always returns true?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I came across the below methods in a piece of code. I am trying to understand the purpose or meaning of why use the always true predicate.

```
private static List<Customer> getTenCustomerRecords(List<Customer> customers) {
    return getFilteredTenCustomerInfo(customers, cust -> true);
  }

 private static List<Customer> getFilteredTenCustomerRecords(List<Customer> customers, Predicate<? super Customer> filter) {
    return customers.stream()
        .filter(filter)
        .sorted(comparing(Customer::getOrderDate).reversed())
        .distinct()
        .limit(10)
        .collect(toList());
  }
```

Comment: You *could* supply a filter that really filters. Apparently this wasn't needed in this particular case

Comment: @HansKeﬆing makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the author wants to make the filtering customer method to be more generic.So he allows the client to input a predicate to define their filtering logic.

Then he can build a more specialized version of the filtering method on top of the generic one by configuring the filter predicate and finally call this generic method.

And in the case that the filtering logic is the same as the generic one , it simply defines the filter predicate as always true. It can help the client to call it more easily as the client does not need to define the Predicate by themselves.

You can start to feel the author 's intention if you try to imagine that in the future there will be many use cases that need to filter different kind of customer such as :

- `getActiveCustomerRecord()`
- `getVipCustomerRecord()`
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for the very good explanation. Every bit of the code now makes sense.